# Public Availability of a good Dataset in PCAP (TCPDUMP) format for IDS/IPS testing

Tags: ids, intrusion, tcpdump

I am trying to pass good reputable malicious traffic from an IPS. There are several sources on internet to explore datasets like the oldest I think DARPA set (not available in pcap format and [not that efficient](https://www.kdnuggets.com/news/2007/n18/4i.html) for modern day use) or NSL-KDD dataset etc. Here is a [good link](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-get-the-latest-dataset-for-a-network-intrusion-detection-system) I found about options that I can look into. However none of them has dataset available in pcap format. Is there any reputable dataset available in PCAP or TCPDUMP or convertable to PCAP?

Comment: Requests for lists of resources are off-topic here as the lists could potentially be never-ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of some of the ones I use:

- https://www.netresec.com/?page=PcapFiles
- https://iscxdownloads.cs.unb.ca/iscxdownloads/CICAndMal2017/PCAPs/
- https://github.com/bro/bro/tree/master/testing/btest/Traces
- http://traces.cs.umass.edu/index.php/Network/Network
- https://github.com/markofu/pcaps
- https://ant.isi.edu/datasets/requests.html
- https://mcfp.felk.cvut.cz/publicDatasets/

In some of the you need to ask for permission.

Comment: Please do not answer request for lists. They are off-topic here.